# Have An Active / Toggle Click Event That Ignores Sibling Elements With The Same CSS Class When Clicked

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, this

I have some elements on a page and I want it so when I click one of them a specific child element is removed, and when the element is re-clicked the child element comes back again.

I would normally do this with a click event which adds an '.active' CSS class which can be added and removed based on whether a variable is currently showing true or false with an if/else statement.

The problem this time is because I have multiple elements I can't really use an '.active' class because if more than one element is 'active' it removes or re-adds child elements inside different parent elements, as opposed to just the one which has been clicked.

In the example code I want it so when I click a red box the yellow box disappears in that box only, and when I re-click that specific parent (red) box the child element only reappears in that specific parent if more than one red box has been clicked.

Because this will affect quite a number of elements I can't really add IDs and write individual functions.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/MWJYMEY

```js
var boxOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".box-outer"),
    boxInner = document.querySelectorAll(".box-inner");

if (boxOuter) {
  boxOuter.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
      // code
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120vh;
}

.box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `toggle` a class `onclick` on the `box-outer` and in `CSS` you can add if `box-outer` has a class of `active` then hide the `box-inner`.

Javascript:

```
item.classList.toggle("active");
```

CSS:

```
.box-outer.active .box-inner {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

---

```js
var boxOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".box-outer"),
  boxInner = document.querySelectorAll(".box-inner");

if (boxOuter) {
  boxOuter.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
      item.classList.toggle("active");
    });
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120vh;
}

.box-outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-inner {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}

.box-outer.active .box-inner {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-outer">
    <div class="box-inner"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

---

> [Check it in action on codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJWyRJr?editors=1111)